# sort object nested and is not an array

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I search how to sort by `place.city` this kind of object who have id's for keys. The need is to keep id's for first keys…

I tried different methods, but I always fail, there is too much keys.

I cannot change the objet, this poor architectured one is returned by an API get and I don't have the hand on it.

```
{
    "123": {
      0: {
        "place": {
            "city": "New York",
            "country": "USA" 
        },
        "person": {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 45
        }
      },
      1: {
        "place": {
            "city": "New York",
            "country": "USA" 
        },
        "person": {
            "name": "James",
            "age": 32
        }
      }
    },
    "456": {
      0: {
        "place": {
            "city": "Chicago",
            "country": "USA" 
        },
        "person": {
            "name": "Louis",
            "age": 34
        }
      },
      1: {
        "place": {
            "city": "Chicago",
            "country": "USA" 
        },
        "person": {
            "name": "Christine",
            "age": 65
        }
      }
    },
    "789": {
      0: {
        "place": {
            "city": "Dallas",
            "country": "USA" 
        },
        "person": {
            "name": "Kevin",
            "age": 27
        }
      },
      1: {
        "place": {
            "city": "Dallas",
            "country": "USA" 
        },
        "person": {
            "name": "Robert",
            "age": 55
        }
      },
      2: {
        "place": {
            "city": "Dallas",
            "country": "USA" 
        },
        "person": {
            "name": "Danny",
            "age": 62
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This kind of filter don't work as expected because of keys in second positions I guess… `var sortedByPlace = _.sortBy(Object.keys(data).map(k => ({id:k, ...data[k]})), (d)=> d.place.city)`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with

```
var transformed = _.sortByOrder(obj, (e)=> { 

if(e.place){

return e.place.city

}else{
return e.name
}
}, ['asc']);
```

the outcome will be an array of your sorted objects.

then you can run

```
var mySortedArr = []
_.each(kkk,(val,key)=>{
   _.each(val,(innerVal,innerKey)=>{
    mySortedArr.push(innerVal)
   })

})
```